# How to save  xaml page content into a jpeg image in windows phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have a xaml page , which i have a scroll viewr . The page content has got more height than the normal screen height, so to view the contnts, u have to scroll down. 
I need to save the content inside the scroll viewr into a jpeg image. how can i do it?

```
<grid height=800>
<scroll viewer height= 2000>
<other contents>
</scrollviewer>
</grid>
```

here i need to save the content inside the scroll viewr? I know how to save the screeen shot, but that wont work out in the case of a scroll viewer.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you scrolling with [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx) method and taking screenshot in parts.

Comment: Will i be able to join them into a single jpeg later? in the mean time let me try out this option.

Comment: Yes, of course. You will get WritableBitmaps which you can join easily, for example see this thread http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/90698/543559.aspx#543559